# Is it acceptable to use positive form of adjectives + not, instead of negative form with prefix (im- in- etc.)?

Tags: adjectives

Is it acceptable to use "**not polite**" instead of "**impolite**"?

And generally speaking about other words in their negative form? By adding a **prefix** only? Can I use "**not + the positive form**" instead?

For example:

> It's **incorrect**. > It's **not correct**.
>
> It's **impossible** > It's **not possible**.
>
> It's **irreversible** > It's **not reversible**
>
> It's **unbelievable** > It's **not believable**.
>
> It's **imperfect** > It's **not perfect**.

Are both sentences valid or acceptable?

Comment: There are times when any of these might be used, but I am not going to provide contexts for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

The best time to use the **not + positive** form is when you are trying to emphasize what it’s not.

> Today, the normally trivial task was impossible.
>
> Today, the normally trivial task was not possible.
>
> Be careful, the damage caused is irreversible.
>
> Be careful, the damage caused is not reversible.

This is not the only case it's used, but probably the most common.